# Is there a PHP plugin for allowing login via major OpenIds and login APIs?

Tags: php, openid, facebook, google-account, multiple-login

Is there a PHP plugin or an open project offering a simple login/connection system to most of the major sign in providers simply by providing an API key then storing the linked account information in MySQL? Or is there a system that can be extended to include various other login providers as they become available?

- [Google Account](http://www.google.com/accounts/) / gmail / blogger
- [Yahoo! OpenId](http://openid.yahoo.com/) / ymail / Flickr
- [Facebook Connect](http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php)
- [Twitter](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/OAuth-Examples)
- [OpenId](http://openid.net/)
- [MyOpenId](http://www.myopenid.com/)
- [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki)
- [Wordpress OpenID](http://support.wordpress.com/settings/openid/)
- [MySpaceID](http://developer.myspace.com/myspaceid/)
- AOL / AIM
- Windows Live

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a plugin but something you add to your site. However, take a look at [Dope OpenId](http://stevelove.org/projects/dope-openid/), it is rather easy to use and handles most implementations for free and you are in total control and not dependent on yet another service.

**Edit:** I haven't checked if it handles *all* of the above, but I have most of them on my login screen and they work.

Comment: The demo's a good start (http://stevelove.org/projects/dope-openid/demo/) and covers a good slab of OpenId sites and works for others not listed in the demo dropdown (eg Google). I guess it's a start that could possibly be extended with my own script or secondary script to include Facebook Connect, Twitter, Windows Live and other login services that don't connect using OpenId...

Comment: I never looked at Windows Live so I can't say anything about that but the only "hard part" I faced was Yahoo where you needed to change some URL in a special file requested by Yahoo or something (unfortunately I have a network problem right now so I cannot reach the server and provide more details but you'll figure it out).