# To add OpenID like SO, do I have to implement each OpenID separately

Tags: php, web-applications, authentication, openid

I see that most sites that allow you to login with OpenID have several OpenID providers listed, like Yahoo, Google, myopenID, etc.

If I want to offer the same features to my site users (allow them to login with their Yahoo or Gmail, etc.) do I have to add each OpenID provider separately? What I mean is, do I have to go and research how to add Yahoo, then go and research how to add Gmail, then go and research how to add OpenID, etc.? or there an easier way to do this?

I work with PHP so any suggestions or libraries that can make this easier are welcome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a PHP plugin for allowing login via major OpenIds and login APIs?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1326181). However, has been a long time since then.

Comment: See also [PHP OpenID Library that allows facebook / openid / twitter, etc;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3237262/php-openid-library-that-allows-facebook-openid-twitter-etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you would have to do provider-specific work to build each integration, test them and maintain them if those providers change their interfaces or APIs.

Or, you could save yourself all the bother of building integrations with each service and instead use a "social login" service like [Janrain](http://www.janrain.com/) or [Gigya](http://www.gigya.com/). They're not free, but they would solve your problem.

Comment: Form what I understand, the problem with Janrain is that I wouldn't be communicating directly with the OpenID providers (yahoo, google, openID, etc.) Janrain is always in the middle, and I have to go through their API. This also means that if yahoo updates their API but Janrain doesn't, I'm stuck with what the man in the middle (Janrain) is allowing me to do. Do I have it right?

Comment: You do not have to care about specific APIs when using OpenID. That's the point of OpenID.

Comment: @sameold - yes, that's basically correct. @cweiske - I agree in principle, but I've been through enough standards in the past and seen such huge differences in supposedly compliant implementations that I would never just take a vendor's word for their service being correctly built.